# Multiplying 2d matrices from 3d tensor

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a 3d tensor A, size(A)=[2 2 N].
I want to get the product of 2x2 matrices:

```
result=A(:,:,N)*A(:,:,N-1)*...*A(:,:,1)
```

This can be done with for loop:

```
result=A(:,:,N);
for i=(N-1):-1:1
  result=result*A(:,:,i);
end;
```

But how would one go about vectorizing this operation?

Comment: are you sure it can be vectorized? I actually doubt it.

Comment: @thewaywewalk No, I am not sure. But it seems like all I need is a slight modifcation of prod function.

Comment: No, it won't be just a slight modification of `prod`. Elementwise matrix multiplication and real matrix multiplication is something completely different. I agree with patrik, the for loop is a good choice in this case.

Comment: no, I doubt that will work. The `prod` function does only multiply the elements in same position for every dimension. Eg, `A` is 2x2x3 matrix. The output of `prod(A,3)` is then `sum=ones(2); for k = 1:3, sum=sum.*A(:,:,k); end`

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I'll stick with fro loop then

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be vectorized with standard Matlab. However, some Mathworks engineers released a very fast MEX implementation of a modified `mtimes`, called `mtimesx`, which *does* support the kinds of things you want to do (and much more). See [MTIMESX - Fast Matrix Multiply with Multi-Dimensional Support](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support), from the docs:

> If `A` is `(2,3,4,5)` and `B` is `(3,6,4,5)`, then `mtimesx(A,B)` would result in `C(2,6,4,5)`, where `C(:,:,i,j) = A(:,:,i,j) * B(:,:,i,j), i=1:4, j=1:5` which would be equivalent to the MATLAB m-code:
>
> ```
> C = zeros(2,6,4,5);
> for m=1:4 
>     for n=1:5 
>         C(:,:,m,n) = A(:,:,m,n) * B(:,:,m,n); 
>     end
> end
> ```